# Community auto-flags Off-Topic -> Other questions closed by a mod

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, community-user, automatic-flags

On [Music](http://music.stackexchange.com) and other beta sites, we have a feature enabled where Community automatically flags questions when they are closed if they have no comments left on them.  This was incredibly annoying till now but at least it made sense.

Currently, if I close as Off-Topic -> Other and fill in a reason, that reason will be left as a comment.  But Community don't give a rip.  Apparently the check happens before the comment is automatically left, so the question still gets flagged with a request to leave a comment.

Can we get this fixed?